# Manually creating actor hierarchy in akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

My application needs to be able to create a tree structure of actors. The standard way to do this I imagine would be to put the instantiation code inside the actors so they can instantiate their children. The approach I would rather would be to be able to instantiate an actor at a given path. Such as create actor A in mySystem and then being able to directly create akka://mySystem/A/B and other actors. Does such functionality exist? It would simplify my code greatly.

EDIT: Now that I'm not on my phone, let me elaborate.

say I have a class

```
class myActor extends actor
```

and I need to make an n-way tree of these. Instead of having the code required to instantiate their own children in the receive function with something like

```
case Create(n:Int) => {}
```

I am looking to simplify the myActor code by not including any of that and instead being able to create my hierarchy at the start of my code manually. So ideally something like this (assuming hypothetical static function "create"):

```
val sys = ActorSystem("mySystem")
Akka.Actors.Create("akka://mySystem/a", new myActor())
Akka.Actors.Create("akka://mySystem/a/b", new myActor())
Akka.Actors.Create("akka://mySystem/a/c", new myActor())
```

which would create the actor tree:

```
  a
 / \
b   c
```

Now, does this exist? Is there a better way to do this without cluttering my actor code with the instantiation code?

EDIT, round 2:

Ok, looks like this functionality doesn't exist. I instead created a sub-trait of actor and forced all my instantiation code in there so that my concrete implementation classes are still tidy.

Answer (score 4):

Your question starts with the postulation of a solution, and it unfortunately does not include a description of the problem.

The actor tree is foremost to be understood as the supervision hierarchy: the parent handles its children’s failures and the life-cycle of the parent places bounds on the life-cycle of its children. Whether or not an actor should be the child of another needs to be determined by considering these implications.

I say that because your question implies that you are modeling the supervision tree according to some other criterion, quite possibly to abuse it as a registry with `system.actorFor` as the look-up mechanism. There may be rare cases where that works, but a priori I would not recommend it; I’d rather put a hash-map inside a dispatcher actor and have that handle the look-up. If you conclude—by measurement—that that does not perform well enough, you can scale it up by using a [router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/java/routing.html).

To answer your question now: each parent needs to create its own children, which mean that it must in one way or another contain the code to do that. You can pass `Props` down the hierarchy to make parts of it configurable, but you should not work around [what supervision means](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/general/supervision.html); ask yourself what should happen if one of the leaves fails, and then ask yourself whether your presumed leaves should be restarted and/or killed when an intermediate actor is restarted.

Comment: I see that theoretically this is a good answer, however I can't help but notice how much spaghetti code results from large actor system hierarchies. A central configuration as mentioned in the question might provide a mechanism for clear understanding of the overall hierarchy for practical software purposes. Would you recommend some alternative method for clarifying complex hierarchies? Or is this just how it has to be given parent-child actor relationships?

Comment: It is difficult for me to answer this because you seem to imply a context that I don’t have. Actor systems are structured in subtrees providing certain functionality, in that sense they are very modular. The entry point to each of these submodules is its top actor, which effectively IS its whole subtree. I can see how breaking this model by trying to install actors within subtrees from the outside would produce spaghetti code, because that is simply not meant to be done. Whenever an actor needs to create a child, it can for example look at the config to determine how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Every actor has a parent. To do what you want, you'd need an `Actor` class to serve as the parent for all the other actors (other than the root actor). Since parent actors are synonymous with supervising actors, you'd want to have some means of dictating the supervision strategy to apply to those parent actors.

I suppose you could define a generic parent `Actor` to place into the interior positions of the actor hierarchy and write a method to decompose an actor path name and create the hierarchy dictated by one or more of those paths. You'd probably want a way to specify the supervision strategy and, minimally, the `receive` function to install in the leaf actor.

Since only an actor can create its children, the parent actors would have to respond to messages for creating their child actors (either other parent actors or leaf actors) somehow coming up with a way to select which `Actor` subclass to instantiate for the leaf actors.

But to answer your question, there's nothing built-in to do this. I don't think it has enough general utility to justify adding it to Akka itself.

Answer (score 2):

Create root actor, from within root actor create your tree with `actorFor`. Use `application.conf` in classpath for static configuration of hierarchy of names, or create some constant structure of addresses. The other option is parse paths and create children in overriden `preStart`. There are different schemes for supervising children lifecycle, do restart and routing messages transparently through a single actor.